# My Pokemon that I've caught only show in my journal and not in my Pokemon folder

Tags: pokemon-go

I've recently downloaded Pokemon go and I've caught a few but they only show when I caught them in my journal and not in the Pokemon folder where it names all the Pokemon that you've caught why is this???

Comment: Can you show screen shots?

Comment: It won't let me upload pics on here but it shows all the Pokemon I've caught in the journal part not the Pokemon folder where it says 0/250 or however many you've caught

Comment: I would say the only explanation is that they were transferred. Have you angered anyone recently?

Comment: Upload a screenshot elsewhere and post the link here.

Comment: If you have another smartphone/tablet try downloading the app on it and logging into your account. It could be specific to just your phone.

Answer (score 1):

Back when your question was asked there were a lot of communication errors and server errors. These have since been resolved.

I too have seen this happen to me once or twice. And I've seen it happen on other people's phones too. This *was* a communication error with the server. The Pokemon are there, just not displayed.